Is it a good idea to tell my recruiter that my availability has changed?
On the 20th of this month I start a new job in a 20 hour per week position in a store that will open its doors next month. Almost a month ago they hired many people at once after a day of group interviews with more than 100 people, including me. I haven't signed the contract yet but I have the pre-agreement. The place and the company are good, so I would like to stay there. My doubt is that this week my availability has changed because I have left school: instead of part-time, I can now do full-time. I want to communicate this to the company because I am interested in working more hours and the idea arises that if full-time vacancies appear before the 20th (because a lot of time passes from the pre-agreement to the actual beginning of the contract, and I think that perhaps someone hired changes his mind), they could count on me.
However, I am afraid that the company will interpret this as something negative and that they will come to the conclusion that they should not hire me because if they cannot offer me more hours of work I will look for another job and I will not be with them for too long. This doesn't have to be this way, I'm willing to wait for vacancies to arise. Furthermore, the company already told me that initially it would be 20 hours a week but that if there is a lot of work they could be extended.
My question is: should I ask them to consider me for full-time positions now, or should I wait to tell them? Money is not an urgency right now and I value above all what will be better in the long term.
Thank you!

You are overthinking it. Just let them know

That you love the company
And you are looking forward to starting work a d having a long future with them.
By the way, you are now available for longer hours and you would like to be considered for  such a position if it comes up.


No harm communicating that your are interested in fulltime - IF AVAILABLE. But make it clear that you are happy with what you've been offered.
By the way - No written offer is worth the paper that it is written on. Be careful.

A written offer with a start date and salary is usually trustworthy, if you have sent back that you have accepted it. But yes, some people recommend that you not consider it locked in until the contract is signed, which may not be until the first day of the job.
